# Static Content with a WAR and Jetty on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, jetty

I have a REST server that is packaged into a WAR and run with Jetty on Heroku. I have a new requirement to server up some simple static content.

This is simple enough, I can put the static content into my "src/main/webapp" and the default servlet will handle it.

However, I do not want to have to rebuild my WAR each time our HTML guy updates the static content. So I have two questions.

1. How do I have Jetty serve up my REST service as well as static HTML content without having to rebuild my war each time the static content changes.
2. How do I push new static content to heroku without having to rebuild my project and restart jetty?

Currently deployment is easy, I only need to worry about code changes so I just put from git to heroku and it calls mvn package and restarts my dynos. But with static content only changes I do not want this to happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few choices for you.

1. Define another DefaultServlet mapping a new request path to a directory on disk.

   - Defined in `WEB-INF/web.xml`
   - or Defined in a Jetty context deployable xml
2. Define a DefaultHandler mapping a new request path to a directory on disk.

   - Defined at the server level in the `etc/jetty.xml`
   - or Added to the list of handlers in a new xml file of your choice, such as `etc/my-external-static.xml`
   - See [`contexts-available/resources.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.12.v20130726/jetty-distribution/src/main/resources/contexts-available/resources.xml) in the distribution for an example.
3. Define a ResourceHandler mapping a new request path to a directory on disk.

   - Defined at the server level in the `etc/jetty.xml`
   - or Added to the list of handlers in a new xml file of your choice, such as `etc/my-external-resources.xml`
   - See [`etc/jetty-fileserver.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.12.v20130726/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty-fileserver.xml) in the distribution for an example.
4. Deploy a static context reference along side of your webapp

   - See the [`context/javadoc.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.12.v20130726/jetty-distribution/src/main/resources/contexts/javadoc.xml) file in the distribution for an example.

The first technique I would try is ...

- Open the [`etc/webdefault.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.12.v20130726/jetty-webapp/src/main/config/etc/webdefault.xml) from the distribution.
- Find the [`<servlet>`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.12.v20130726/jetty-webapp/src/main/config/etc/webdefault.xml#L117-L173) declaration for the servlet named `default` DefaultServlet.
- Copy the `<servlet>` definition over to your webapp's `WEB-INF/web.xml`
- Rename the `<servlet-name>` to something other than `default` (its a special reserved name).  Lets call it `<servlet-name>extrastatic</servlet-name>`
- Add a new `<init-param>` defining a `resourceBase` value pointing to where on disk to look for content.

```xml
<init-param>
  <param-name>resourceBase</param-name>
  <param-value>/var/web/static/</param-value>
</init-param>
```

- Add a `<servlet-mapping>` section defining what URL patterns to serve this static content from.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>extrastatic</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

- Now deploy your war again.

How this works ... is that you now have extra static content outside of the webapp.

Assuming you have your war deployed to the context `/myapp` then requests to URL like this would serve content from this new `extrastatic` servlet.

```
http://machine.corp.com/webapp/static/ 
   serves: /var/web/static/ (possibly index.html - see dirAllowed init-param)

http://machine.corp.com/webapp/static/css/main.css
   serves: /var/web/static/css/main.css

http://machine.corp.com/webapp/static/js/jquery-min.js
   serves: /var/web/static/js/jquery-min.js
```

Comment: Thanks Joakim. I think I may be over thinking this. Maybe the simplest thing is to create a new maven WAR module with just the static content in "src/main/webapp" and use maven war overlay capabilities to have my rest server WAR depend on that static WAR. Then I have to do nothing and my static content is isolated in its own module. Still doesn't solve the Heroku slug compilation issue but it should be good enough.